# AWS -. Manage windows/Linux ec2 VMs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I have a question, regarding managing AWS VMs on a system level. On azure cloud i was using CSE extensions to run powershell scripst and manage/configure VMs. I AM looking for similar solution for AWS cloud. I was thinking about SSM dosuments, but that is not a good choice i suppose.

Comment: SSM documents are quite useful for handling the configurations within the EC2 instances.Why do you think it is not a good choice?

Comment: I need to make some modifications to the Windows VMs registry for example. Using ssm documents can i do this? i need to run a script for os configuration modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [runPowerShellScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-plugins.html#aws-runPowerShellScript) SSM Run Command:

> **Run PowerShell scripts** or specify the path to a script to run. This plugin runs on Microsoft Windows Server and Linux operating systems.

This allows you to run any PowerShell script on your Windows instance, on condition that it is [setup to work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up.html) with System Manager.

Comment: OK, great, I see that we can use inline scripts, run scripts located on a specific VM, but is there any possibility to use scripts located in the s3 bucket for example?

Comment: @tester81 You could download them when you run your command and then execute. I am not sure whether you can execute them directly from S3. Don't think so.